# How to install dryscrape in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, python

I run this code in terminal in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo -H pip install dryscrape
```

But after run this code show this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: dryscrape in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: xvfbwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from dryscrape)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from dryscrape)
Requirement already satisfied: webkit-server>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from dryscrape)
```

How to issue this problem?

Comment: Try running the command without sudo.

Comment: @Tom , I run this code without sudo but show this error display.